# Wifi: no hardware installed, then flashing question mark when restarting

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I bought my laptop ( MacBook Pro mid 2012 or 2011) I have 10.11.2 OS X elcaptain. 
This entire thing started few days ago. I was watching a movie late at night on my laptop and I think I probably slept and forgot to close my laptop. I woke up closed it. Few hours later, I opened it to access the internet I get the option of wifi: no hardware installed. I've never seen something like this before. So, I restarted. It didn't work. Today, my friend told me to shut it down then press command and r when I open it and restoring my laptop that might make it work. Now, I did this and the computer asks for Internet recovery, but it can't connect in the first place. I shut it down. I opened again and there's a question mark in a folder flashing. Then I shut it down pressed command and r and it gives me option to choose a network and the option is x literally. I can't ask for Apple support's help as I am out of the country for vacation and I can only wait until I'm back by the 8th of January, and I really need my laptop to work. Any suggestions? Please?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no major external force (drops) or liquid damage to the computer.

IT sounds like your hard drive is not "happy" and at the very least you might your hard drive directory repair beyond what Apple's built in tools disk utility / FSCK can perform.

[Disk warrior](http://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/) is an excellent option for hard drive directory repair when the built in tools are not sufficient.

To be quite honest it sounds like your hard drive is failing. One unlikely scenario (still possible) is your hard drive SATA cable, optical drive etc.. one another part is bad making look like a hard drive issue.

I would have a tech take a look at your computer before you tinker with it too much, sounds like waiting until you return is your best option.